# Do we need to publish odom in tf if we are using robot_localization?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, base-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My question could seem simple, however I didn't find clear answer for that. I have noticed that if I am using **robot_localization** pkg I don't need to provide more than 1 absolute source of robot position.

My question, do we need provide for example tf changes in the driver node, I mean odom->base_footprint, if I am using robot_localization. Because **robot_localization** providing odom->base_footprint as well.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382856/do-we-need-to-publish-odom-in-tf-if-we-are-using-robot_localization?/) by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2021-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your ros system uses odometry, you should make sure that only one node publishes transform `odom->base_footprint`, and only one node publishes transform `map->odom`. This is why the nodes in the robot_localization package usually have a parameter to enable/disable publishing to `/tf`.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on 2021-07-21**:
@Mike Scheutzow so If robot_localization publish odom->base_footprint transformation, I shouldn't publish odom->base_footprint from driver?

Am I correct?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-21**:
Correct. Some ros systems have multiple sources of odom->base_footprint, and in that case they must all be combined into a "best guess" before one node publishes the value.

**Comment by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on 2021-07-21**:
@Mike Scheutzom Thank you!